# Create a post with user_register doesn't create title

Tags: user-registration

I've got my user registration to automatically create a post with the user_register hook however the title shows up as (no title) can someone help me with what I'm doing wrong here?

```
add_action('user_register','create_new_user_post');

$userinfo = get_userdata($user_id);
$disname = $userinfo->display_name;

function create_new_user_post($user_id){
        if (!$user_id>0)return;

        // Create post object
        $my_bio_post = array(
           // 'post_type' => 'ggs_user_post_type',
             'post_title' => $disname,
             'post_content' => 'Put cool content here!',
             'post_status' => 'publish',
             'post_author' => $user_id
        );

        // Insert the post into the database
        $bio = wp_insert_post( $my_bio_post );

        //and if you want to store the post ids in 
        //the user meta then simply use update_user_meta
        update_user_meta($user_id,'_bio_post',$bio);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `create_new_user_post()` can't see:

```
$userinfo = get_userdata($user_id);
$disname = $userinfo->display_name;
```

Place those within the function so that the function has access to those variables.

Answer (score 0):

`$disname` is not set. You define it outside the function's [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). The same is true with `$userinfo`. And you don't have `$user_id` set either. It is passed into the function by the `add_action` mechanism. You need to pull both of those into the callback function as Josh said (and pick *his* answer. He got here first, and the answer is correct,  just not very detailed. Consider this "supplemental".)

```
function create_new_user_post($user_id){
    if (!$user_id>0) return;

    $userinfo = get_userdata($user_id);
    $disname = $userinfo->display_name;
    // and the rest
```